# Creating a Curved/concave shape from a flat surface

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm attempting to create a retro style TV in blender but I've come to a halt. The basic shape is done but I want to create the concave inside of the TV screen.

I tried to do this first by placing a flattened sphere and using the Boolean modifier to mold the concave shape into the main model. However now this looks terrible and out of place, and I want to make this look better, but I have no idea how.

Here's what my model looks like now
[image: Badly Modeled TV]
Any Help is gladly Appreciated!

Reference image:

[image: Reference image]

Comment: I would try creating a separate plane for the screen, subdivided enough, and then use proportional editing tools to "grab" it towards outside... getting a rounded shape... I've lloked at some 50s tv sets reference pics, though, and the box "hole" usually less squared... having your reference would help find the best solution...

Comment: Please add reference photo which is only partially seen in screen provided.

Comment: Appologies, LukeD. I will do that next time.

Comment: m.ardito, Thank you for the suggestion! I gave it a try and it worked well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your reference, the TV tube s not so "spherical", so I won't start from a sphere. I tried to get something like that:

[image]

in a very simple way.

1. I created a vertical plane, and subdivided it about 40 times.
2. then I added a lattice object all around the plane
3. adjusted lattice subdivision settings: U:1, V:5, W:3
4. applied a lattice modifier to the plane mesh, targeting lattice object of course
5. then pulled some "front" lattice vertices outwards, obtaining a soft, uniform deform to the plane
6. built a rough tv set box around the deformed plane

I can't detail more all steps now, I'm in a hurry, but I provide a sample .blend below, so you can see the setup. Let me know if you need more detail.

[image]

Comment: This helped lots thanks! It taught me a handful of new things (Didnt even know what lattice was/what is was for before this)
Thanks alot again!