# How to bend nurbs surfaces

Tags: modeling, workflow, nurbs-surface

I modeled a simple flat square, adding thickness by extruding.
Now I want the Surface to not be flat but a Kind of buldged.
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: You can use proportional editing with grab, or a lattice modifier targeted to your mesh. See this for reference: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63425/creating-a-curved-concave-shape-from-a-flat-surface/63428#63428

Comment: Basically, don't use nurbs surfaces unless you have very special needs. Nurbs are outdated technology. Use meshes.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon you are new to 3d modeling , hence the question seems strange since you started out with a box. Nurbs modeling is a completely different beast. Let me try to help you out.

First of all, just like ibalazscs says nurbs are seldom used these days, its has proven itself to be quite a clumsy tool in regards to modeling. We deploy something else call "box modeling". Basically starting from a box or a simple plain we can create an estimate of an object surface and later add a modifier "Subdivision Surface"

This is what I mean ... on the left is a model that started out as a plane. I extruded the edges and created a draft form. After which I add a modifier to the model (Copied and selected highlighted in orange)...

[image]

**After that there is a further step you may need to do to complete the look of a nice smooth curve surface.**

The thing about curved surface in a 3d world is that you need more than one face to create the illusion of a curved surface. Yes illusion! All the surface you see in a 3d software are planes... using smooth surface shader those straight and flat planes hides their true edges, making them look like a smooth surface. Without smooth shader the model would look like this...

[image]

And here is the exact same model with the same number in vertex and face count, smooth shading applied...

[image]

Lastly, here are the steps to apply smooth shader...

1. Select the model.
2. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.
3. Hit <kbd>W</kbd> to display special drop down menu.
4. Select "Shade Smooth" from list.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get your theme from?

Comment: I designed it myself after using blender for professional work for 2 years now. I started with the default dark tone theme that comes with blender default install and slowly change those color over time as I used the software. I came from a 3dsmax background , and been on 3dsmax for 15years before I switched.

Answer (score -1):

Ok my active 3d-time lies 13 years behind me. I used to model with 3d-max and Maya. I am new to blender and absolutly flashed what this package can do.

Yesterday I reduced my question to my core problem. In my sparetime I want to model a logo. That logo is rounded and has nice curves. Thats why I decided to start with nurbs.

That's the logo and I am open to the ways you would model.

[image]

Comment: Box modeling can do actually anything you want, all you need to do is throw in a subdivision modifier and you can get to whatever resolution you want. Of course, the details on the model have to make logical sense as to how far is the viewing distance. If your model is only going to be 10% of the screen space, you don't have to overdo it... in fact you could even get away with deploy an alpha texture in your scene.