# Is there an easy way to convert a flat horisontal surface into a curved (domed) one?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am building an asset for City Skylines. This will be a station building with curved end walls (like a Church Apse) and a slightly domed roof.

I have built the basic structure out of a cube and 2 half cylinders with a bit of manual editing to remove redundant faces.

However I am stuck as to how to turn the currently flat roof into a domed structure. I could I guess take a sphere and edit this down to the shape I want, but I wonder if there is a quicker way to turn a flat surface into a domed one.

There is an answer here, [Creating a curved surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63425/creating-a-curved-concave-shape-from-a-flat-surface) but sadly I do not know enough about blender in order to understand the procedure.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/pipe-with-round-caps-ends and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38861/how-to-close-a-pipe-with-a-perfect-hemisphere/

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the suggestions. However the 1st does not match my issue at all and suggests using half spheres which I already mentioned in my question. The second has a possible solution, using bevel, however when I try I get this - https://i.imgur.com/xEW3pwv.jpg not really what I was after. Anyone any thoughts?